# iOS startMonitoringForRegion didn't work in Sleep mode (black screen)

Tags: ios

I am trying to write an app in iOS for the iPhone 4 using startMonitoringForRegion that fires a local notification each time the location delegate receives a location update.

As long as the phone is awake (the screen is lit up), the application works well, firing the notifications, but when I put the phone to sleep (the screen is black), I no longer receive notifications until I wake the phone up by pressing the home button

I'm tried to add "Required background modes" - "App registers for location updates" key in info.plist but it's make no sense...

CLLocationManager delegate is setted up as AppDelegate.

What do I need to do in order for location updates to register even when the device is asleep? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the CLLocationManager instance has been deallocated after the application is closed.

For me, I would create a singleton of location manager with a CLLocationManager property and the delegate set to the singleton. After that, I would call the method `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` to make sure the app receives location update. It will work even if the app is killed.

For the case if the app is killed, I will need to instantiate the location manager singleton in the app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
    //instantiate the singleton here
    NSArray *regions = [[[[LocationManager sharedManager] locationManager] monitoredRegions] allObjects];
}
```

I explain it more here for the difference between using significant location changes and standard location service: [location based push notification when app is not running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737446/location-based-push-notification-when-app-is-not-running/16560912#16560912)